# Master page modification

Tags: sharepoint-designer, master-page

If a create a new Site and then open it in SPD then navigate to Master Pages I see a `default.master`, a `minimal.Master` and a `v4.master`. Which one do I change if I want all the quick links `s4-leftpanel` reducing\increasing in size?
Will this only affect the Site I have opened in SPD or will it affect all Sites in the Site Collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find your sites current master page by opening below URL

```
 http://weburl/_layouts/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx
```

Now you can open designer and modify the correct master file.

You don't need to worry about other sites, unless you propagate changes to subsites.

Comment: In SPD I have created a new page from v4.master but I do not get the option to select it when I go to 'http://weburl/_layouts/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx'. Are you saying I should just change the v4.master instead and it will only affect this site? Thanks

Comment: To change master page you need to enable publishing feature. In your case you can update `v4.Master` since that is your default master page.

Answer (score 2):

You should never change an existing "system" SharePoint master (if you update SharePoint those updates can potentially overwrite the "system" masterpages, removing your customizations. If you want to change things, copy the SharePoint master which you are currently using (see answer of Amal Hashim). Copy that masterpage (e.g. with SharePoint designer). And edit that masterpage. I would create a new CSS for it and add it to the newly created (copied) masterpage.

Comment: This is what I thought. When I select new page from master it saves the new page in 'SIte Assets' not master pages so I can not select it using Amal's method

Comment: Select the something.master (e.g. seatle.master) of the desired site in SharePoint designer (under masterpages) just crtl+c and crtl+v (copy - paste) rename it and you're done. New page from master creates a new page which uses that masterpage. You can also set this new masterpage from designer (set as default master page)

Answer (score 0):

If this is sharepoint team site, It will be mostly V4.msater, unless someone has made changes to the master page before you.

If you right click V4.master page and "Set this as default master" option is disabled then V4 is your current master page. Same applies to other two master pages.

It wont affect other sites.